# Algebra equation with ln need help simplifying

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was helping out my little brother with his math homework and I came across a question I'm pretty sure is unsolvable without the use of a graphing calculator. I don't think it's possible to simplify it by hand to a point where you can solve with just the ln function on a calculator. It's been a while since I've done math, so can anyone confirm for me?

$$\frac{120000}{1+48e^{-0.015t} } = 24e^{0.055t}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=e^{0.055t}$, then we have:

$\frac{120000}{1+\frac{48}{x^\frac{3}{11}}}=24x$

Hence:

$120000=24x(1+\frac{48}{x^\frac{3}{11}})$

which gives us the equation:

$5000=x+48x^\frac{8}{11}$, let $y=x^\frac{1}{11}$

And so we have:

$5000=y^{11}+48y^{8}$

So yeah...get out your graphing calculator.

Comment: The equation currently reads as $e^{\color{red}{-0.015t}}$ on the left, but $e^{\color{blue}{0.055t}}$ on the right.  It is not the same $x$ on left as on right.

Comment: Sorry I misread that.

Answer (score 0):

Let $t = 200 \ln x$.  Then we can rewrite the problem to:
$$
120000 = 24 e^{11 \ln x} + 24 \times 48 e^{8 \ln x} = 24 x^{11} + 24 \times 48 x^8.
$$

This is again equivalent to $x^{11} + 48 x^8 - 5000 = 0$. Hence we have to find a solution to this polynomial, which is absolutely non-trivial and can only be done using numerical methods.  So yes, I would advise taking out your graphical calculator.

Comment: Is there a way to prove that such equations can only be solved by numerical methods?

Comment: better applied http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5E%2811%29%2B48x%5E8-5000%3D%3D0

Comment: @J.Gudal: There are indeed ways to prove that about equations, although I am not 100% sure about this one as I thought it not worth the immense effort. ;) It might very well be possible that $x$ is algebraic.